# Environment Variable in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wanted to create a docker-compose file, but the following seems to fail:

```
...
services:
  test:
    ...
    volumes:
      - ${FOO}:/bar
...
```

I've read that environment variables are not evaluated in keys, only in values. But since the `$FOO` is a value, I thought this would work?

Answer (score 3):

This works. You have to declare `FOO` somewhere to get the result. Following code will work:

**caller.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
export FOO=/home
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Could I also use `docker-compose build` followed by `docker run -it ...` ?
Or does this maybe not mount the specified volumes?

Comment: You can use whatever you want. Just shown you that you need to declare and `export` this variable before using

Comment: The variable is defined in my .bashrc, I'm just trying to find out why `/bar` is non-existent in my container.

Comment: `echo $FOO` on host -- what is the result?

Comment: `echo $FOO` gives `/home/***/Documents/Scripts/bar` where `bar` is a directory containing some files.

Comment: Okay I found it. When I do `docker-compose run container /bin/bash` it does add the volume, but `docker-compose build container` followed by `docker run container` does not add it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

So apparently it does work to expand environment variables that way.

But `docker-compose build && docker run` does not mount these volumes automatically, opposed to `docker-compose up` (or `docker-compose build && docker compose run`).

If someone could explain this behavior, I would be glad.

Comment: Because `docker run` has nothing to do with your `docker-compose.yml` file. If you want to mount volumes with `docker`, not `docker-compose`, use generic syntax like `docker run -v $FOO:/bar`